# Can methanol act as a ligand?

Tags: acid-base, coordination-compounds, lewis-structure

As methanol is both a lewis acid and a lewis base, the lewis base part suggests that it can act as a ligand as many bases are. So, is methanol a ligand? And what is the reason behind it?

Comment: To me, the presence of lone pairs is enough of a reason.

Comment: If water can act as a ligand, why can't methanol?

Answer (score 1):

There are several complexes where methanol acts as ligand. Some examples are:

1. **methanol coordinated vanadium(V) chalcogenido complexes**: $\ce{V(Chal)Cl2(OMe)(HOMe)2}$ where $\ce{Chal = O, S, Se}$
2. **bis(μ-methoxo)dichromium(III) complexes**, $\ce{[(L^{Se})2Cr2(μ-OCH3)2(CH3OH)2]}$ and $\ce{[(L^{Se})2Cr2(μ-OCH3)2(CH3OH)(CH3O)]}$, where $\ce{L^{Se}}$ represents the dianion of 2,2‘-selenobis(4,6-di-tert-butylphenol)
3. **di-µ-chlorido-bis[dichloridobis(methanol-κO)iridium(III)] dihydrate**  $\ce{[Ir2Cl6(CH3OH)4]2H2O}$
4. $\ce{M(CH3OH)3SO4}$ where $\ce{M = Ni, Co, Zn}$

**Reference**

Google: Methanol ligand complex. First 4 search results.